# File Input - File not being read QT

Tags: c++, file, qt, input

I'm very new to C++ and QT. Basically, I just done Java stuff, but we're being thrown in C++ for a module, in which we have to design a Zork game UI. The way I am planning to create the Room object is have the Room constructed with a roomnum.long, .short and .name for the long desc, short desc and name.

For the first room, I'm just going to load the file directly for the moment until I get onto objects etc properly. However, I can't seem to get the file written into a text label. The return "restart game etc" does get written on button press, but not the contents of the file. The Rooms folder is in the same folder as the source file (islandmain.cpp in this case)

Any ideas?

```
void TheIslandMain::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    ui->roomDesc->setText(readFirstRoom("/Rooms/room1.long"));
    ui->roomDesc->setWordWrap(true);
}

QString TheIslandMain::readFirstRoom(QString filename)
{
    QFile mFile(filename);

    if (!mFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not open file for reading Line 31";
        return "Could not load file. Please restart game.";
    }

    QTextStream in(&mFile);
    QString fileInput = in.readAll();

    qDebug() << fileInput;

    mFile.close();

    return fileInput;
}
```

Comment: Remember that paths starting with '/'  are _absolute_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the file exists using `bool QFile::exists(const QString& path)` and also if its only the filename you have in your function or the whole path (path is needed)

soo long zai

Comment: That helped in that it shows that the file doesn't exist, but I know it does so it must be a path program. What would be the correct way to look for it.

The file structure is

maindir which contains .cpp and .h files
maindir/Rooms which currently only contains room1.long, room1.short, room1.name

Comment: try ... `QString QDir::currentPath () [static]` and see if it is your application folder, than just add your `filename`to it and it should work

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on this. I was under the impression, from Java, that when I was pulling a file using a class, that the root dir was the only the class file was in. So if I had dir/whatever.class and I was calling file.file, it would need to be in dir/file.file. If it were in another dir, say dir/foo/file.file, I would need to just use  foo/file.file in the whatever.class?

Comment: Aha! QT is using the build path!

Answer (score 0):

`/Rooms/room1.long` points to a file in root, then Rooms, then room1.long as the file. If `Rooms` is the directory it needs to be relative to the application itself, so if `Rooms` is in the same directory as your application it'd just be `Rooms/room1.long`, if it's in a higher level `../Rooms/room1.long` or `Resources/Rooms/room1.long`.

Comment: Cheers! It was actually going into a sep dir (Island-BUILD) so ../Island/Rooms/room1.long did the job.